# Docusign api create/upload a template using php

Tags: php, docusignapi

Let's say i have a file like below at the following path:

```
C:\workspace\myfiles\file.docx
```

And i want to create a template in docusign using the file in the path. How can this be achieved? I have searched long for this and read docusign's api documentation but i don't see a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Your question could be clearer:

Do you want to send an envelope that includes the document? Use [Envelopes::create](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/).

Or do you want to create a template that others can use, where the template will include the document? If this is your question, why do you want to create the template programmatically (via the API)?

Typically, templates are created infrequently, so it is usually easier and quicker to use the DocuSign web tool.

If you do want to create a template programmatically, use the API call [Templates::create](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/Templates/create/).

(If you want to add more details to your question, please **edit** your question to add the additional information.)

Comment: I want to create a template with the the docx file itself. Whereby similar to going to the web tool and uploading a docx as template but i want to achieve this with docusign api

Comment: @CloudSeph Use the Templates::create call